# javascript simulate mouse click on specific position

Tags: javascript, click, mouse, position, simulate

I need to now how to fire a mouse click event on a button automatically.
I have this but doesn't work  :(

```
window.setInterval(function() { simulateClick(); }, 2000);

function simulateClick() {
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", false, false, window, 0, 684, 571, 684, 508, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        var a;
    a.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Oscar

Comment: My guess is that you're not initiating a. IT just says "var a;" but you never specify which element it is. Other than that I think it looks fine.

Comment: If you want to simulate for testing purposes you can use selenium http://seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Looks like you're trying to do this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-using-javascript/6158050

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is click a button, button elements have a `click` method that can be invoked:

```
<input type="button" id="theButton" onclick="javascript:alert('The button was clicked!');" value="A button" />

<script language="javascript">

setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("theButton").click();
}, 1000); // wait one second then click the button

</script>
```

There's no need to "actually" simulate the mouse click at a specific x,y position.

Comment: There's IS need. thinking a input text with cursor position changing.

Comment: @JiangYD that's a different. question. You can set the position of a cursor in a text box like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-cursor-position-in-html-textbox

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if its posible to do that on javascript but if you need automatic and periodic clicks maybe you can do that with external tools like [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)

Comment: mmmmm ,aybe..... is it possible to move the pointer mouse automatically to certain position on the web page?

Comment: with autohotkey you can send a click on the specific coordinates see this [page](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm)