# Automatic keyboard language change when changing the input field

Tags: html

I have many input fields with two languages in the same page.
Is there a way to change the language of the keyboard from Arabic to French once the user changes the input field?

Comment: "*the language of the keyboard*"?

Comment: @Tiny: the platform-specific "input language" setting. In e.g. Windows you can manage input languages via that keyboard icon in systray (or at least in control panel). You can use Alt+Shift key to switch between input languages. OP apparently want to let the webapp automagically take care about this platform-specific step of switching between input languages once the enduser tabs from one to other input field.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776543/how-to-catch-event-keycode-and-change-it-to-another-keycode