# Trigger other key rather than original key using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am try to trigger " ` " keyCode = 192 when I press " enter " keyCode = 13. I am trying below code but it is not working in contenteditable div. Any idea?
And how to $apply this?

```
$scope.pressKey = function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 13){

    event.preventDefault();
    var e=angular.element.Event('keydown');
    console.log(e);
    e.which=192;
    $('#regularDot').trigger(e);


    } 

<div id="regularDot" ng-keypress="pressKey($event)" class="wf-loading" 
ng-model="regularDot" contenteditable="true" n></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to catch event.keyCode and change it to another keyCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776543/how-to-catch-event-keycode-and-change-it-to-another-keycode)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use pure JS methods like `KeyboardEvent()` it has cross browser support issues, use jQuery instead.

Now `angular.element` has basic support of jquery but it does not support Event() method which you used. So best approach is having jquery library in your codebase (with its script tag attached before angularjs in index.html). Then change your code to as follows:

```
$scope.pressKey = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {

        event.preventDefault();
        var e = jQuery.Event('keypress');
        console.log(e);
        e.which = 192;
        e.keyCode = 192;
        $timeout(function() {
            $('#regularDot').trigger(e);
        });
    } else if(event.keyCode == 192){
        console.log("Newly triggered event catched with keyCode " + event.keyCode);
    }
}
```

Here I've made just few changes like adding trigger method inside `$timeout` so that it'll wait small time to complete the `preventDefault` of previously triggered event before setting (triggering) new event, and doing `$apply` also. I've changed newly triggered event type to `keypress` instead of `keydown` so that after triggering event you'll be able to handle it using ng-keypress on that element (with id regularDot).

Similar **[plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/8uSWc7YdeRknlCj7W26N?p=preview)** to refer.