# Overwrite textbox value

Tags: html

I need to overwrite the value in the textbox.

I have a form and for some reason I need to completely overwrite the value in the text box.
For example, the text box with id 'city' and the default value is 'Mumbai'.

```
<input type="text" id="city" value="Mumbai">
```

But if the user changes it to some other city, it should completely overwrite or select the whole word thouroughly, without having to press backspace for 6 characters.

```
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761508/change-html-textbox-overwrite-instead-of-insert-as-user-types][1]
```

The above link shows overwriting in text box. I want to delete the whole value in one go.

Comment: What have you tried so far??

Comment: Very unclear question. Please go ahead and add some data on what all are the things you have researched, like @Usman said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use javascript `select` function in `onClick` event.

```html
<input type="text" onClick="this.select();" id="city" value="Mumbai">
```