# How to push cursor to the next line when user hits ctrl + enter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a textarea, where if the user hits enter, it causes the form to submit, but if he hits ctrl + enter, I want it to move to the next line.

This is the code that I'm using, within my function which is called on keypress by jquery:

```
if ( (e.keyCode == 10 || e.keyCode == 13) && e.ctrlKey)
    //move to next line here
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Couldn't you just use e.preventDefault(); and then add \n to the textarea value?

Comment: I would appreciate, if you would add more example code, the textarea, the binding etc. Bonus points for giving us a jsfiddle snippet :)

Comment: Just finished a working example down below @Robin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all set now! Breakline at any point & it maintains position (all while trying to use the most up to date browser techniques with fallbacks for IE, etc).

[UPDATED x2 - jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ejLF6/4/)

```
$('#sillyTextarea').keydown(function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode === 10 || e.keyCode  == 13 && e.ctrlKey) {
        // Ctrl-Enter pressed
        // keyCode 10 is actually for Chrome (whacky I know...)

        var el = document.getElementById('sillyTextarea'),
            allText = $(this).val(),
            currentPos = getCaret(el),
            beforeText = allText.substr(0, currentPos),
            afterText = allText.substr(currentPos);

        $(this).val(beforeText + '\n' + afterText);

        setCaretPosition(el, currentPos);
    }
});
```

With help of 2 functions

`function getCaret(el) { }`

[Caret position in textarea, in characters from the start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea)

`function setCaretPosition(el, caretPos) { }`

[Set keyboard caret position in html textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-cursor-position-in-html-textbox)

Comment: Should be all set! Any reason why shift-enter doesn't work already?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.parentElementClass').on('keyup', 'textarea', function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey && (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13)) {
        $(this).val(function(i, val) {
            return val + '\n';
        });
    }
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/dDYcq/2/)

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` will do nothing here since `keyup` is not a cancelable event.