# set cursor dynamically to div, when in designMode

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I have this text in a textbox. The document body has designMode set to on. (| is the cursor)

```
<div><h3>Hi there</h3><p>Welcome| to the page</p></div>
```

After clicking a button, the text writes the innerHTML of a div.

**Question:** From the position of the cursor in the textbox, can I set the cursor to that same position in the DOM.

---

### Hi there

Welcome| to the page

---

Thanks.

Comment: possilbe duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/q/512528/474535](http://stackoverflow.com/q/512528/474535)

Comment: Nah that is setting the cursor position in a textbox, I want to set it in the DOM that is in designMode.

Comment: You mean you are editing the html text and at the same time you want to update the rendered html with the same cursor position?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how bad you want to do this. The closest method that I can think of is setting a `span` at cursor position in the textbox and then setting the cursor to the position of that `span`.

- Use [jQuery Caret](http://www.examplet.buss.hk/jquery/caret.php) to get the position of the cursor in a textbox and save it in a variable(Caret uses `$.browser` to get browser info which is removed from jQuery 1.9.1 and above and moved in to a separate plugin. So you will need to use the latest of 1.8)
- On Button click insert `<span id='cur-pos'></span>` at the index of the string(value stored through Caret)
- After the html is updated get position of span and move the cursor to that position.