# jquery focus and select on input:text

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `textbox` and put the data like file name (e.g. `Mydata.doc`). I want to select the text from the textbox but I don't want to select all text. I just want to select `Mydata` exclude extension `.doc`. Is there any way to get this.

Comment: Its pretty painful, what your looking for is to set 'caret' position, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-cursor-position-in-html-textbox

All the commenters seem to think he wants to split a string, not what he wants to do I think :s

Comment: Sorry for duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lastIndexOf()`.

```
var val = MyData.value;

// base name
var name = val.substr(0, val.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

Answer (score 1):

common way to do:

1. get the file name like mydata.doc as a string
2. find the index of the last "."
3. delete the chars from the index of the last "."
4. you will get the file name without extention

hope it can help!

Answer (score 0):

This Should work for you

```
var textboxData = $('.textbox').val();
var newData = textboxData.split('.');
alert(newData[0]);
```

Here is the **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mZtyX/)**

Comment: `file.name.with.multiple.periods.doc`

Answer (score 0):

jquery is javascript.  Read the whole string and call the js function split() on the string.

Answer (score 0):

as i tested, i find what we get from input file of html is with a disk path such as "c:\one.jpg".so i update my answer below:

common way to do:

1. get the file name like G:\mydata.doc as a string
2. find the index of the last "." sIndex
3. find the index of the  last '\' eIndex
4. get the chars from sIndex+1 to eIndex
5. you will get the file name without extention

[image: my test, and it does help]
hope it can help!

[image]