# jQuery move Cursor Back "X" amount of Spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor

I need it so that when a button is pressed, the cursor will:

1) Locate the end of the sentence
2) Move the cursor back from the end of the sentence "x" many spaces (x is a variable);

Here's a fiddle -----> [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcP9q/) <------

HTML

```
<span>From the end, move the cursor back this many spaces: </span>
<input type='text'   id='num' size='5'/>
<button>Submit</button>
<br/><br/>
<textarea>The cursor will move in here</textarea>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
   var myval = parseInt($('#num').val()); //the number of spaces to move back
    //code to move cursor back - starting from the END OF THE STATEMENT
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-cursor-position-in-html-textbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd do that like so :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var el      = $('textarea')[0],
            myval   = parseInt($('#num').val(), 10),
            cur_pos = 0;

        if (el.selectionStart) { 
            cur_pos = el.selectionStart; 
        } else if (document.selection) { 
            el.focus(); 

            var r = document.selection.createRange(); 
            if (r != null) {
                var re = el.createTextRange(), 
                    rc = re.duplicate(); 
                re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark()); 
                rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re); 

                cur_pos = rc.text.length; 
            }
        }  

        if (el.setSelectionRange) {
            el.focus();
            el.setSelectionRange(cur_pos-myval, cur_pos-myval);
        }
          else if (el.createTextRange) {
            var range = el.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', cur_pos-myval);
            range.moveStart('character', cur_pos-myval);
            range.select();
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jcP9q/3/)