# triggering AngularJS ng-model pipeline onBlur

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, directive, angularjs-ng-model

I have this `$parser` which limits the number of characters that user has entered:

```
  var maxLength = attrs['limit'] ? parseInt(attrs['limit']) : 11;

  function fromUser(inputText) {
      if (inputText) {
          if (inputText.length > maxLength) {
              var limitedText = inputText.substr(0, maxLength);
              ngModel.$setViewValue(limitedText);
              ngModel.$render();
              return limitedText;
          }
      }
      return inputText;
  }

  ngModel.$parsers.push(fromUser);
```

I want to use this directive on an input element which has `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"`, but there is a problem that the whole `$parser` thing gets executed after user loses the focus of input element, I want it to get executed as user types into the input field.

```js
(function (angular) {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('app', [])
    .controller("MainController", function($scope) {
      $scope.name = "Boom !";
      $scope.name2 = "asdf";
    }).directive('limitCharacters', limitCharactersDirective);

    function limitCharactersDirective() {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: linkFn
        };

        function linkFn(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            var maxLength = attrs['limit'] ? parseInt(attrs['limit']) : 11;

            function fromUser(inputText) {
                if(inputText) {
                    if (inputText.length > maxLength) {
                        var limitedText = inputText.substr(0, maxLength);
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(limitedText);
                        ngModel.$render();
                        return limitedText;
                    }
                }
                return inputText;
            }

            ngModel.$parsers.push(fromUser);
        }
    }

})(angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  without ng-model-options: <input type="text" ng-model="name" limit-characters limit="7" />
  
  <br>
  with ng-model-options <input type="text" ng-model="name2" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" limit-characters limit="7" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user inputs some value in input `$setViewValue` is called internally. As stated in [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setViewValue) this is what `$setViewValue` does:

> When $setViewValue is called, the new value will be staged for
>   committing through the $parsers and $validators pipelines. If there
>   are no special ngModelOptions specified then the staged value is sent
>   directly for processing through the $parsers pipeline. After this, the
>   $validators and $asyncValidators are called and the value is applied
>   to $modelValue. Finally, the value is set to the expression specified
>   in the ng-model attribute and all the registered change listeners, in
>   the $viewChangeListeners list are called.
>
> In case the ngModelOptions directive is used with updateOn and the
>   default trigger is not listed, all those actions will remain pending
>   until one of the updateOn events is triggered on the DOM element.

What it means is that `$parsers` are used only on actual model change commit (which in your case happens on blur).

The easiest solution to your problem would be to not use `$parsers` to limit the characters. Check other solutions in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701205/how-can-you-limit-the-value-from-input-using-angularjs).

Using the most upvoted answer you can modify your directive to make it look like this:

```
function limitCharactersDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: linkFn
    };

    function linkFn(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
        var maxLength = attrs['limit'] ? parseInt(attrs['limit']) : 11;
        angular.element(elem).on("keypress", function(e) {
            if (this.value.length == maxLength) e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
}
```

[Check this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vvL0jnw0/1/) for a working example.

Comment: very well written, but I have one issue with the new directive , when user copy and paste into the directive, it wont notices it. any idea?