# Angular limit input[number] length

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using the directive in [How to limit input[number]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701205/how-can-you-limit-the-value-from-input-using-angularjs) cause a issue.

When in input reached max I want to mark the input(double right click on the input) and then pressing a digit to make it change the entire input don't change it, due to the directive `e.preventDefault();`
The selection event can be view in:

```
angular.element(elem).on("select", function(e) {
                console.log(e);

            });
```

What is the best way to fix it?
The directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('limitTo', limitTo);

function limitTo() {    
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var limit = parseInt(attrs.limitTo);
            angular.element(elem).on("keypress", function(e) {
                if (this.value.length == limit){
                    e.preventDefault();
                } 
            });
        }
    }
};
```

And use:

```
    <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg"  limit-to="6" 
    ng-model="vm.details.m_inputSMS" placeholder = {{vm.configProprs.kodPlaceHolder}} name ="m_inputSMS" id="m_inputSMS"
    ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"required/>
```

Comment: Please add some codes. What have you tried so far?

Comment: added, it is the same is the original question.

Comment: tried replacing the value with the new one, not sure it is the best way.

Comment: Thanks, but where is the `double right click` logic in this codes?

Comment: There is not, I don't know how to handle selection(double right click) and inserting a new value when the limit is reached.

Comment: But why do you want to use `right click`. Right click is meant to be the browser context menu. Sorry, this is not my cup of tea. Good luck.

Comment: Double right click on the input.

Comment: Hi you could use this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/numeric-formatter

Answer (score 0):

So to solve this issue I used `window.getSelection().toString()` and make sure the selection match the input:

```
if(this.value.length == limit && window.getSelection().toString() == this.value){
     //logic goes in here...
}
```

Comment: Where is the double right click behavior in this solution?

Comment: The double click insert value into the selection string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give limit to input field then using `ng-minlength="6"` `ng-maxlength="6"` this you can assign limit in angularjs.

```
<input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg"  ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="6"
    ng-model="vm.details.m_inputSMS" placeholder = {{vm.configProprs.kodPlaceHolder}} 
    name ="m_inputSMS" id="m_inputSMS" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"required/>
```

Comment: By using ng-minlength and ng-maxlength you can entered value of 6 digits only in input field.

Comment: Post a fiddle for it.