# Maxlength using angular JS is not working for input type text

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to set `Max-length` for `input` element using `angularJS` but its not working for me. Below is what I tried.

```
 <div class="billcutofdate vLine vLineRight" id="SAPExecutiveBillDate">
            <a><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Billing Cut-off Date <span class="badge">{{BillCutdate}}</span></a>
            <div class="setcutofdate">
                <div class="inputNumber clearfix"><input ng-maxlength="2" type="number" step="1" value="0" class="form-control" ng-model="BillCutdateSet" /></div>
                <button class="btn btn-default customBtn" ng-click="changeBillDate()"><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Set Date</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Can anyone tell me why its not working as I am new to angularJS

**UPDATE**

**REPRODUCING ERROR**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>








<input ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="2" min="1" max="31" type="number" step="1" value="0" class="form-control" ng-model="BillCutdateSet" />
```

Comment: What does it mean that is not working? If you try to validate the form the angularjs way does it says is valid? If you want the browser no to let the user to type more than something, use maxlength attribute + ng-maxlength for angularjs validation

Comment: @f-CJ: Not working means I am able to add characters digit more than 2 numbers. See my updated question that I tried

Comment: ng-maxlength is not going to prevent that, html attribute maxlength does that

Comment: ok, but how can we do that using `angularJS`

Comment: even html attribute is not working

Comment: You have to use a combination of both: ng-maxlength is gonna be useful to validate the field, html maxlength is gonna help to prevent user to input more characteres than allowed. Or you use a custom directive to substitute maxlength but I don't think it is necessary

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize it is a number

Comment: With a custom directive https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701205/how-can-you-limit-the-value-from-input-using-angularjs

Comment: I tried this `ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="2" min="1" max="31"` and its working fine, but I am able to enter text as `e` in the textbox..why ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192096/discussion-between-f-cj-and-b-n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a simple functionality but sometime browser gets confused if the input `type=number`.

So by taking some reference from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701205/how-can-you-limit-the-value-from-input-using-angularjs) see Raghavendra's answer. I tried this and achieved it.

```
<input ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="2" min="1" max="31" onkeypress="return (event.charCode !=8 && event.charCode ==0 || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57))" readonly="readonly" type="number" step="1" value="0" class="form-control" ng-model="BillCutdateSet" />
```