# Pure Javascript - onfocus set caret position to 0

Tags: javascript, caret

I found a possible solution to my question, however, since I'm new to javascript I can't seem
to get the desired behaviour.

The solution is posted by mcpDESIGNS here

[Set keyboard caret position in html textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-cursor-position-in-html-textbox)

What I wish to have is force the caret position back to 0 as soon as the field is focused
I have created a fiddle which will help demonstrate what I'm doing.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KuLTU/

```
addLoadEvent(function() {
document.getElementById("search_string").onfocus = search_field_focus;
});

function search_field_focus() {
    setCaretPosition("search_string", 0);
}
```

I assume the why I'm calling setCaretPosition is wrong, any suggestion?

Comment: The solution over there wasn't working for me as well..

Comment: You have to be a little more specific than that, since it seems to work for plenty of other people. What isn't working? And are you getting and errors/exceptions in your log?

Comment: Also, either way, this is a duplicate. You should be asking your questions in that thread, not this one.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I click the actual textbox I have I expect the caret position to be in the beginning. Check out my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/khx2w/

Comment: The question has been revised, please assist.