# Javascript - onfocus set caret position to 0

Tags: javascript

I found a possible solution to my question, however, since I'm new to javascript I can't seem
to get the desired behaviour.

The solution is posted by mcpDESIGNS here

[Set keyboard caret position in html textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-cursor-position-in-html-textbox)

What I wish to have is force the caret position back to 0 as soon as the field is focused
I have created a fiddle which will help demonstrate what I'm doing.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KuLTU/

```
addLoadEvent(function() {
document.getElementById("search_string").onfocus = search_field_focus;
});

function search_field_focus() {
    setCaretPosition("search_string", 0);
}
```

I assume the way I'm calling setCaretPosition is wrong, any suggestion?

Comment: In your fiddle, I can't seem to get it to execute the `onload` event, hence the onfocus function is not assigned. (To test this, try adding an `alert('test')` in the `addLoadEvent(function() { ... })` funciton)

Comment: just another solution: maybe you want to select the whole text, so the user can write new text to it. you can do it with this: `<input type="text" onfocus="this.select()" value="Search..">`.  Alterantive: clear text by yourself with `this.value=""`. Alternative: set a palceholder -> `<input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="Search..." />`

Comment: Well, it does work with an actual html file. The behaviour I'm aiming for is the the text cue to be placed at the beginning of the field as soon as its focused. (Alternative to the placeholder attribute behaviour)

Comment: In your fiddle, change `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <head>`.  Then it should work.

Comment: Done. http://jsfiddle.net/KuLTU/3/ What's next ? any idea why the code is not working?

Comment: Seems fine to me. Cursor is set to pos 0 when I click into the field. What exactly is not working?

Comment: You click the textbox and the cursor is always placed at the beginning ? What browser are you using?