# Set cursor to specific position on specific line in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, textselection, text-cursor

I am trying to somewhat duplicate the "autocorrect" functionality seen in programs like Microsoft Office's Outlook.

For starters, anytime a user types "a " (the letter a and a space) at the beginning of a line I want to change that text to "*Agent ["

I have written the below which works fine if you are typing along in the textarea from top to bottom. **But if you type anywhere else in the textarea the text is changed then the cursor moves to the end of the textarea.**

I want the cursor to always be placed at the end of the changed text.

I have the line number that was changed in the variable `currentLineNumber` and i know the cursor needs to be after the 8th character in that line but I am unsure of how to tell it to go there

Ideally id like to something like

```
function setCursor(row, position) {
 //.... code to set cursor 
}
```

What can I do to accomplish this? Im open to a javascript or jQuery solution (although I find jQuery a little difficult to read and understand)

If there's a better way to achieve what I need overall, I'm open to that too.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eghpf/) if you don't understand the issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set cursor position in html textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-cursor-position-in-html-textbox)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle see: http://jsfiddle.net/eghpf/2/

I've added var `currentPosition` which is used in this method

```
function setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
  if (input.setSelectionRange) {
    input.focus();
    input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
  }
  else if (input.createTextRange) {
    var range = input.createTextRange();
    range.collapse(true);
    range.moveEnd('character', selectionEnd);
    range.moveStart('character', selectionStart);
    range.select();
  }
}
```

Which comes from this [jQuery Set Cursor Position in Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area)

What happens (is the reason why the cursor is always on the last position); is when you call `$('#systemNotesbuilder').val(arrayOfLines.join("\n"));` the entire value gets overwritten with a new value placing the cursor after that new value. The call to set the cursor is (and should) be after that call.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was much lesss painfull than I was excpecting and I can understand how this works. perfect!