# simple textarea string replace jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I'm trying to make some simple jquery script that replaces a specific string in the textarea. I've got this know:

```
$("textarea").bind("keyup", function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    text = text.replace(/,,/g, "′");
    $(this).val(text);
});
```

This replaces `,,` into the unicode symbol `′`. This works, except that the cursors position moves to the last character of the textarea everytime there is a replacement. I want that the cursors goes just after the `′` when there is a replacement. How could I do this ?

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zvhyh/

Edit: thanks for the help guys. I use this now:
http://jsfiddle.net/zvhyh/14/

Comment: possible duplicate of [update textarea value, but keep cursor position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286595/update-textarea-value-but-keep-cursor-position)

Comment: I would check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [set cursor to specific line in a textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858174/set-cursor-to-specific-position-on-specific-line-in-a-textarea) as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on it:

http://jsfiddle.net/zvhyh/11/

```
$("textarea").bind("keyup", function() {
    var cursorPosition = $('textarea').prop("selectionStart");
    var text = $(this).val();
    if (text.indexOf(',,') > -1) {
        text = text.replace(/,,/g, "′");
        $(this).val(text);
        $('textarea').prop("selectionStart", cursorPosition - 1);
        $('textarea').prop("selectionEnd", cursorPosition - 1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your updated fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/zvhyh/10/**

The key is to use `selectionStart` to get the current position of cursor and `setSelectionRange` to place the cursor in that position later on.

```
// get current cursor position
var pos = $(this).val().slice(0, this.selectionStart).length;

// replace the text
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/,,/g, "′"));

// reset the cursor position
this.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
```

Hope that helps.

Update:

Because two characters are being replaced by one character, in the above code the cursor position will skip one character to right. One workaround is to first check if a ",," combo is there, and then use the position as one character before.

Updated fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/zvhyh/13/**

```
if (text.indexOf(",,") > 0) { 
...
pos--;
..
```

Comment: Now it moves one character too much to the right. If I type ,, somewhere not on the end of the textarea.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this method tough. When I do `pos-1` I get very weird  things.