# Removing Text selection in EditTextCell

Tags: gwt, celltable

In GWT Celltable while editing EditTextCell the textbox value gets selected by default, how to remove this default selection?

you can check this celltable showcase for EditText also,

http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellSampler

Answer (score 0):

When you click on an `EditTextCell`, it calls the `edit` method which focus and select the content:

See [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/cell/client/EditTextCell.java#257)

```java
protected void edit(Context context, Element parent, String value) {
    setValue(context, parent, value);
    InputElement input = getInputElement(parent);
    input.focus();
    input.select(); /* HERE */
}
```

Maybe you can create a custom class extending `EditTextCell`, overriding this method without the last line...

Comment: Yes i override edit method and removed input.select(), now the selection gone but the focus is on the starting of the text, how to reset focus to the end of the text?

Comment: Sorry I have no clue about moving the cursor with GWT function... This is possible in javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-cursor-position-in-html-textbox