# Cursor at the begining of the text

Tags: javascript, cursor

I want to set the cursor to the beginning of the textbox`(<input/>)` always. 
I found following code below which does the job. However if there is a text in the textbox `(<input/>)`already, cursor is set at the end of the text first, then moved to the beginning. Which causes the jumping effect which is undesirable.

Is there a way to always set cursor to the begging without this jumping effect? Note I have function below called in onFocus onClick.

```
var range;
if (elem.createTextRange) {
    range = elem.createTextRange();
    range.move("character", 0);
    range.select();
} else if (elem.selectionStart) {

    elem.focus();
    elem.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just to it with jquery?
 `$( "#target" ).focus(); `

Comment: ...god forbid he do it in native JS...

Comment: Of course, calling `$( "#target" ).focus();` doesn't actually do what is asked for.

Comment: What do you mean by "textbox", `<input/>`, `<textarea/>` or `contenteditable` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set cursor position in html textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-cursor-position-in-html-textbox)

Comment: The question is not exact duplicate. OP wants to remove the jumping effect, while the duplicate question just asks about positioning the cursor t particular poistion.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative instead of doing it all by yourself is following jQuery plugin:

http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs

A nice Demo can be found here: 
http://rangyinputs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/textinputs_jquery.html

Hope this brings some new light into your task, please understand that without a plunker / jsfiddle a perfect solution is out of my scope right now.

**Update**
Another way would be to use (if you are in html5 context) the attribute `autofocus`. But the behavior is, that it gets the focus when the DOM was rendered and all existing text is selected. Don't know if you can live with this.

```
<input type="text" value="some text here" autofocus />
```

**Update2**

http://plnkr.co/Wag8fb @OP: please fork & edit it, so it works like your code. Because I used all your code pasted here and its not working at all.