# GWT syntax highlighting in TextBox

Tags: java, gwt, syntax-highlighting

I have a TextBox in a GWT app I'm building that's used for advanced searched. I'm trying to find a way to use syntax highlighting for certain characters sequences (e.g. the string #title, or just #T) in the search string, but I can't find anything about how to allow for coloring of individual symbols. I suppose I need something more complex than just a TextBox but I'm not sure what to use. Would it perhaps be possible to do with a single-line, stripped down RichTextBox, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it with an input. Use a FlowPanel (or simply a div element), and set [ContentEditable](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable) on it. Most browsers support it now. Then you can insert regular HTML tags (bold, span) inside the text on KeyUpEvent, and you can style the spans anyway you like.

Comment: This works with the exception that the caret position resets to the first character with every keyUp. I'm using a HTML (which is compiled into a div) wrapped in a FocusPanel (for keyUpHandling), and it doesn't have any get or set caret positions. I was trying to post a few line of codes but I can't get the indentation to work...

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-cursor-position-in-html-textbox

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really know JavaScript. I've tried just copying it into a native method but it just keeps returning 0.