# Get Textarea Cursor Position in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs, selection-api

This question boils down to needing to get the cursor position of a `<textarea>` element in a directive. In short, all I need to work in this.

```
var position = element.selectionStart;
```

There are at least 5 answers on the subject using various methods, e.g. [this one for angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574295/set-caret-position-in-input-with-angularjs), [this one for some jQuery extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976574/how-to-add-a-text-to-a-textbox-from-the-current-position-of-the-pointer-with-jqu), [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308292/inserting-text-at-cursor-in-a-textarea-with-javascript/3308539#3308539).

I have read them all and decided to just try to get the selection start object. Here is my [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/vIr2GIidEK30AnyRGLk6?p=preview). I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Note - the background change stuff is to see whether or not I am selecting the right element, which I am. Edit here is a snippet of the code that fails:

```
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          var textArea = elem.find("#itemTextArea");
          textArea.bind('click', function() {
              //This gets to undefined, even though selectionStart is a property of textarea*
              scope.testValue = elem.selectionStart;
          });
      },
```

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/selectionStart

P.S. Click on text area to immediately know what's happening in directive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The syntax you are looking for is:

```
scope.testValue = textArea.prop("selectionStart");
```

Comment: Wow. I spent my day trying to fix this. I guess that's what I get for not using jQuery and recognizing it. Thank you very, very much. Accepting in a minute.

Comment: Glad I could help you.

Answer (score 3):

This also seems to work

> scope.testValue = textArea[0].selectionStart;

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Accepting jbrown's answer because he was first.