# Creating a text box with template text that does not disappear when user selects

Tags: html, asp.net, templates, textbox

I'm currently trying to add a new free form text box with preset values (i.e. Name:   Age:   etc.) that do not disappear when a user selects the box like placeholder text. So far, I've only found solutions for using default/placeholder values which is not what I want. Does anyone know if there is a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you had a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324252/html-keep-placeholder-when-user-types

Comment: Hi Oscar, I did find that question yes, but I'm not wanting to use a placeholder, this text needs to stay in the text box and allow the user to edit it rather than it disappearing on select. Not sure if this is possible really.

Comment: <textarea>You mean like this?</textarea>