# Make words in placeholder while typing in javascript

Tags: javascript, placeholder

I want to make do a typing accuracy check application. What I want to achieve is to make the words (user should type) in the `placeholder` or similar to the effects of `placeholder` while users are typing.

When user types the words in the `input`, the word in placeholder should disappear or fit the words in the `input` (user can't see it).

I have checked several other examples on stackoverflow, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324252/html-keep-placeholder-when-user-types), but nothing helps me.

This the effect I want to acheive[image]

Could anyone give me some ideas and solutions of how to solving this?

I have been struggled with this for a long time.

Thanks for any responds!

*Sorry, my english sucks. [I want to something like this in this website](https://monkeytype.com/)

Comment: Take a moment to inspect the source of the website you're trying to copy. You will notice they are not using `<input>` tags at all. They are using plain `<div>` tags for each word, inside a container with `display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap`. Their cursor is mocked, it's not the native cursor and their entire UX is based on `keyUp` event listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this. https://jsfiddle.net/dgstcu0y

Summary of what I tried here is below :

1. I add event listener that will take input and insert into our `div` which is like custom input.

   const input = document.getElementById("input")
   const content = document.getElementById("content")

   ```
   input.addEventListener("input",(event)=>{
       const value = event.target.value
     content.innerHTML = value
   })
   ```
2. Then, I make the input transparent. But the problem is it also make the cursor transparent. So, I tried to add `|` after our custom-input div.
3. Using CSS I tried to to overlap our custom div with generic input.

   .wrapper {
   position: relative;
   width: 300px;
   }
   #input {
   color: transparent;
   padding: 0;
   background: transparent;
   }
   .custom-input {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   color: grey;
   z-index: -1;
   }
   #content:after {
   content:"|"
   }

Here is HTML skeleton.

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <input id="input">
  <div class="custom-input">
    <span id="content"></span>
    <span>My Suggestions</span>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Customize it according to your need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Alok, but for the link you give me, it is changing the `my suggestions` (like the placeholder)?

Comment: You can change its style. You can see that "My Suggestion" is not changing. You can change/insert your suggested text using javascript. I also visited to the linked website. They are using event listener to accomplish those styling. In short they are not using input to display what user is typing.