# Identifying removed characters in a string

Tags: javascript, string, character, detection

In HTML `input` of type `text` I'd like to identify adding or removal of particular characters at their exact location.

E.g. predefined value of text input is string `aa`. User manipulates the string, using all kinds of editing - striking `Backspace` and `Delete` keys, selects text and deletes it \ replaces by another text. The final result of the manipulation is string `a`.

I'd like to know if:

- first `a` was removed
- last `a` was removed
- both `a`'s were removed and new `a` character was added

One of my ideas is assigning each character some kind of unique id that may be used to identify deletion of particular character, but i have difficulties implementing it.

I can use all kinds of Javascript tools and libraries for in-browser usage.

Comment: Does it matter, which `a` was removed?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use onFocus / onChange / onKeyUp on the input node and then track all buttons pressed and the caret position ? You should figure out the rest by yourself :)

Just store the original value in a var and see what changes to it are being done and track them. When the input loses focus or buttons are no longer pressed you can finalise the function / unplug it. That's it.

Here there are some useful links on how to track key and caret but I am sure there are planty more :

[Set keyboard caret position in html textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-cursor-position-in-html-textbox)

http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=5144

[JavaScript multiple keys pressed at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once)

Wdyt?

Comment: I considered that approach, but i'm too lazy to implement it. let's see may be someone already has the implementation : ]

Comment: If you are looking for OOTB solution then maybe you should consider using something more powerful than text input, like ckeditor. There is for example loopindex: https://github.com/loopindex/ckeditor-track-changes