# How to replace the pressed character only; Using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events, jquery-events

Let's say there is textarea with already present text for example: ***AA***. How we can detect the pressed key and change only *this* character with something else. Now if ***A*** key is pressed through keyboard text should become ***AAB*** already existing ***A*** characters are unaltered but newly pressed ***A*** key should write ***B*** in textarea.

The code I have is

```
<textarea>aa</textarea>

<script>
    jQuery('textarea').keyup(function (e) {
        //THIS REPLACES ALL THE TEXT NOT JUST THE PRESSED CHARACTER
        //Need code that should replace just this pressed key not all text of textarea
        jQuery('textarea').val(jQuery('textarea').val().replace(/a/g, "b"));
    });
</script>
```

Ideal solution will select character from pressed key `e` and replace it, but if not possible then maybe replacing last character in textarea can be a poor workaround.

Also ok if `keypress`, `keydown` or similar event is used.

Comment: have you checked `e.keyCode`?

Comment: Side note: please consider how your requirement interacts with selection - typing single character can replace selection (whole text/part) - make sure you understand what you want to do in such case.

Comment: Seems too broad to me.

Comment: when do you want to replace the text in textarea ? starting from which character ?

Comment: @DanielCheung yes e.keyCode gives what key is pressed but `if (e.keyCode==65) e.keyCode = 66;` don't work. How can I replace The pressed key even after knowing its code

Comment: What is expected result when third character within `textarea` ?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov my code is wrong that is why i mentioned comment, what replace is doing there is Wrong. What is needed is explained in question

Comment: @Arkantos don't need 'string replacement' I need the pressed key character replaced with something else

Comment: You need to add some more context here. When you say `key should be replaced`, you need to be specific. Should you replace when you enter a specific key, if so what are the allowed keys and their replacements.

Comment: @Arkantos Whenever A is pressed B should be written in textarea without replacing already present A characters of textarea

Comment: Does that mean that you're `textarea` will always have some default text and if the user starts to edit it your replace should kick-in ?

Comment: @Arkantos Yes. I think I can make what I need out of DanielCheung's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Since `e.keyCode` is read-only. I stopped it from entering and added altered characters.

Credits to MarkPiezak, part of code from here: [Set keyboard caret position in html textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-cursor-position-in-html-textbox)

```js
$(function(){
  $("#ta").keydown(function(e){
    var newKey = e.keyCode + 1;
    var newChar = String.fromCharCode(newKey);
    $("#pressed-key").text(e.keyCode + "->" + newKey + "->" + newChar);
    if (e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 91) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var cursorPosition = $('textarea').prop("selectionStart");
      var ta = document.getElementById("ta");
      ta.value = [ta.value.slice(0, cursorPosition), newChar, ta.value.slice(cursorPosition)].join('');
      setCaretPosition("ta", cursorPosition+1);
    }
  });
  
  //This one is from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-cursor-position-in-html-textbox
  function setCaretPosition(elemId, caretPos) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);

    if(elem != null) {
        if(elem.createTextRange) {
            var range = elem.createTextRange();
            range.move('character', caretPos);
            range.select();
        }
        else {
            if(elem.selectionStart) {
                elem.focus();
                elem.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
            }
            else
                elem.focus();
        }
    }
  }
  
  
  $("#ta2").keydown(function(e){
    var sentence = "I am a monster!";
    if (e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 91) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var ta = document.getElementById("ta2");
      ta.value += sentence[ta.value.length] || "";
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="ta">aa</textarea>
<p id="pressed-key"></p>

<hr>
<p>This one is just for fun. Try answering this: Who are you?</p>
<textarea id="ta2"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I think I can get what I need out of this code, 'll edit ur answer a little and accept.

Comment: @XIMRX you should tell me what I need to edit. Because this is my answer :)

Comment: Ok :) the problem is when clicked at start or middle to add characters there, it adds them at end not where required.

Comment: This can be done using `var cursorPosition = $('textarea').prop("selectionStart");`

Comment: @XIMRX Well, I've not thought of that one :D not thorough enough on testing. Haha

Comment: Gracias @DanielCheung :)