# Prevent blur behaviour on input element

Tags: javascript, html, preventdefault

```js
document.body.querySelector("input").addEventListener("blur",
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
  });
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Upon the blur event,if the string typed in the input would overflow, the shown area is scrolled back to the start. My snippet does not seem to prevent that behaviour. Is there any way to pull this trick off?

```
input.value =   "aaaaaaaaaaabbb"
input.sketch = "|___________|"   
inpur.ideal  =    "|___________|"  //just an aligned visual aid
```

When input lose focus bbb is no longer shown,I would like to prevent the scroll back to start automagically.

Comment: Thank you for the edit @nem035

Comment: Are you comfortable with jQuery?

Comment: You're welcome amigo. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-cursor-position-in-html-textbox) and the question it links to for related info to your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`preventDefault()` on an input's blur event does not prevent the scrolling. What you'll actually need to do is capture the input's `scrollLeft` position when the blur happens and then force the browser to reset it after it tries to do the scroll. See the code snippet below.

On blur, we capture the input's current `scrollLeft`. Next, we reset the `scrollLeft` position wrapped in a `window.setTimeout()` to ensure the browser waits to render the queued change.

```js
document.body.querySelector("input").addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
  var scrollLeft = event.target.scrollLeft;
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    event.target.scrollLeft = scrollLeft;
  }, 0);
}, false);
```

```html
<input>
```