# Change ctrl+left/right arrow behaviour in Firefox (or Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, textedit

In both Firefox and Chrome, in a text field (input box, text area, editable div), ctrl with the left/right arrow keys moves the caret a word at a time.  On a Mac it is the Alt key. When combined with shift it creates a text selection.

But in Firefox when there is punctuation, it moves to end of the current word, including any punctuation. Whereas in Chrome, it moves to the end of the word, then you press it again to move past the punctuation. In a typical sentence you need more keypresses to get to the end in Chrome.

I've been told Microsoft Word behaves like Chrome. In a quick LibreOffice test they are subtly different: Chrome is stopping either side of a punctuation mark, whereas LibreOffice jumps to the end of the word before the punctuation mark, but the next press jumps to the end of the next word, before its punctuation mark.

So, the `*` shows where the caret ends up as I ctrl+right arrow through this example:

```
Chrome:        my* list* (*A*,* B*,* C*).*
Firefox:       my* list* (A,* B,* C).*
Libre Office:  my *list *(*A*, *B*, *C*)*.*
```

This is driving a few users crazy who have to switch between these editors.
Is there a way to take control of this behaviour in our web app? Or, inside the user's Firefox (or Chrome) settings? Or do I have to close this request as a "Won't (Can't) Fix" ?

(It is mainly when editing in a contenteditable div this crops up; we are open to replacing this with one of the numerous text edit web components. Do they tend to take control of this ctrl+arrow key behaviour and implement it themselves? Or are they also stuck with however the browser does it? Examples of components that do allow this level of control would be very welcome, especially if they are open source so I can see how they do it.)

Comment: _"This is driving a few users crazy"_: they have to press a key _one less/more time_. You've clearly done enough due diligence and investigation, and if this only affecting a few users you'll have to weigh the cost/benefit of coding a solution. Personally I would close it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `e.preventDefault()` on a event listener for Ctrl-arrow keystrokes and move the caret manually using [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-keyboard-caret-position-in-html-textbox)