# Cursor position, jquery

Tags: jquery

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area) I found and answer on how to position the cursor in a textarea.

I am creating a jquery chat and I wanted to create a simple html textarea, having a div infront of the textarea displying the html contained in the textarea.

Mark posted the following script:

```
$.fn.selectRange = function(start, end) {

        return this.each(function() {
                if(this.setSelectionRange) {
                        this.focus();
                        this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
                } else if(this.createTextRange) {
                        var range = this.createTextRange();
                        range.collapse(true);
                        range.moveEnd('character', end);
                        range.moveStart('character', start);
                        range.select();
                }
        });
};
```

Witch works fine, but my problem is, how do I find the end position in the div of the html displayed there?

Comment: I don't understand the question. "end" is about the TEXTAREA selection, do you understand that? So what do you want to select in the textarea?

Answer (score 0):

If by showing the HTML contained in the textarea you mean your chat can contain tags like `<img>` and `<a>`, you need to escape the tags. I'm guessing that is what you want, so try this:

HTML (for reference)

```
<div id="formatted"></div>
<textarea id="textchat"></textarea>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#textchat').keyup(function(){
  var txt = $(this).val();
  txt = txt.replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
  $('#formatted').html(txt);
 })
})
```

*Note: you could replace `keyup` with `keydown` or `keypress` but I find the it works better with `keyup`.