# move cursor to the beginning of the input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

when you click on 'Ask question' here in Stackoverflow you see a text "What's your programming question? Be descriptive."

i want the same thing and all i need for that is to move my cursor to the beginning of the text field. how do i do that with jquery?

Comment: There are additional (and better, imo) answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984311/delete-default-value-of-an-input-text-on-click , which was asked 5 months after this one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area

Comment: Also, a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8190890/1617737

Answer (score 32, accepted):

May be that is an overkill, but these functions are helpful to select a portion of an input field.

The code below place the cursor to the first char of the second field.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>so</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input value="stack" />
    <input value="overflow" />
    <script>
        var inp = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[1];
        if (inp.createTextRange) {
            var part = inp.createTextRange();
            part.move("character", 0);
            part.select();
        } else if (inp.setSelectionRange) {
            inp.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
        }
        inp.focus();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the `createTextRange` piece of this answer can be omitted if you aren't supporting Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 19):

You can use focus() method. If I recall jQuery, its like this:
    $("#question_input_field_id").focus();
(If I got your question right)

Update:
Setting cursor at the beginning:

```
$("#question_input_field_id").focus();
$("#question_input_field_id").get(0).setSelectionRange(0,0);
```

Comment: if i got a text in a text field then if i use focus the cursor will be at the end of the text field after the text. i want it to be at the beginning before the text.

Comment: Got it. Updated my original answer. Works with Firefox (i.e. Gecko browsers), not sure about others.

Comment: You can't use the jQuery object with setSelectionRange. This will work: $("#question_input_field_id")[0].setSelectionRange(0,0);

Comment: @Andre just posted the correct answer in this comment thread.

Comment: I am editing the original answer as suggested by @Andre to avoid confusion.

Comment: setSelectionRange is undefined for my side

Answer (score 6):

if you look into the source code of stackoverflow > ask question, you will find this:

```
<table style="width:668px"> 
     <tr> 
         <td style="width:50px"><label for="title">Title</label></td> 
         <td style="padding-left:5px"><input id="title" name="title" type="text" maxlength="300" tabindex="100" style="width:610px" value=""> 
              <span class="edit-field-overlay">What's your programming question? Be descriptive.</span> 
         </td> 
     </tr> 
</table>
```

what really is happening is that a CSS code made the `<span class="edit-field-overlay">` move over the top of input box and show hide when needed... and just do what Sejanus' suggested.

Comment: haha..that was pretty 'lame' to be honest...but well...it worked:)

Comment: hehe.. sometimes, things can be easy... if you just don't overlook at a problem... you just have to trick the eye.. :)

Comment: +1 I found this particular sorcery to be exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure that the cursor will be after the value on focus.
It is widely supported by all browsers.

```
var inpu_val = $("#my_input").val();
$("#my_input").val('').val(inpu_val).focus();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('#txtYourTextBox').blur(function () { 
    var val = $("#txtYourTextBox").val();
    $("#txtYourTextBox").val('');
    setTimeout(function () { $("#txtYourTextBox").val(val); }, 20);
});
```

Comment: Looks like this code caches the value of the input, clears it, then reapplies the same value. All of this happening every time focus leaves the input. I'm not sure how this is supposed to answer the question.