# Possible to know the position of the text cursor in an input field

Tags: javascript

If a user is typing in an input field, I know that you can focus on the element to put the cursor there, but is there a way to position the cursor in the input? say half way? thanks

Comment: Do you want to set it or get it? Make up your mind.

Comment: Related (though about `textarea`): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function GetCursorLocation(CurrentTextBox)
        {
            var CurrentSelection, FullRange, SelectedRange, LocationIndex = -1;
            if (typeof CurrentTextBox.selectionStart == "number")
            {
                LocationIndex = CurrentTextBox.selectionStart;
            }
            else if (document.selection && CurrentTextBox.createTextRange)
            {
                CurrentSelection = document.selection;
                if (CurrentSelection)
                {
                    SelectedRange = CurrentSelection.createRange();
                    FullRange = CurrentTextBox.createTextRange();
                    FullRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", SelectedRange);
                    LocationIndex = FullRange.text.length;
                }
            }
            return LocationIndex;
        }
```

associate this function to the onkeyup, onkeydown and onmouseup and onmousedown to get the location tryit out over [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bYTxn/)

Comment: maybe its too late its firefox issue on jsfiddle. try console.log in fiddle istead of innerText. This function works fine.