# cursor position on focus

Tags: jquery

The cursor position on focus is wrong does not default to 0 position it goes to wherever I click it does anyone have any suggestions?

```
 $('input[type="text"][name="name"]').focus(function() {
$(this).setCursorPosition(0);
}
```

Would something like the above work I can't see anything in my code thats causing this.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area

Answer (score 0):

It's because .setCursorPosition is not a classic jQuery method. There are, however plugins for this.

```
new function($) {
  $.fn.setCursorPosition = function(pos) {
    if ($(this).get(0).setSelectionRange) {
      $(this).get(0).setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
    } else if ($(this).get(0).createTextRange) {
      var range = $(this).get(0).createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      range.moveEnd('character', pos);
      range.moveStart('character', pos);
      range.select();
    }
  }
}(jQuery);
```

<sub>Taken [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/499126/764846)</sub>

Comment: What does the .get do? And what language is it?

Comment: Seriously? It's JavaScript, just like jQuery. It seems worrying that a lot of questions seem to suggest people think jQuery and JavaScript are different languages.

Comment: @SamuelLukeAnthony: it's jQuery

Comment: @Alex: yeah, unfortunately :(