# moving the cursor position in a text-box

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a web application using asp.net. There is a text box(not Rich text-box) which contains a HTML source file, and a list-box which lists out the errors in that file. When a particular error message in the list-box is selected, the cursor point should point out that particular error position in the text box.

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the vertical position of the cursor, but this answer might put you in the right direction I guess (hope you are talking about text area) ->

[jQuery Set Cursor Position in Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area)