# browser console error for custom jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, browser

I found this simple jquery plugin from [jQuery Set Cursor Position in Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area) and it's working great. But one issue is I am getting an error in firefox and chrome consoles

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'setCursorPosition'
```

What I am doing is really simple as following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//to set text cursor
(function($) {
  $.fn.setCursorPosition = function(pos) {
    if ($(this).get(0).setSelectionRange) {
      $(this).get(0).setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
    } else if ($(this).get(0).createTextRange) {
      var range = $(this).get(0).createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      range.moveEnd('character', pos);
      range.moveStart('character', pos);
      range.select();
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
....
textboxArray.get(0).setCursorPosition(0);
</script>
```

Any hint for the reason I am getting the error above will be appreciated.

Update: Thanks to Blender, embarrassingly following solved the problem.

```
textboxArray.setCursorPosition(0);
```

Comment: Why is there `.get(0)` everywhere? Get rid of it and see what happens.

Comment: @Blender You have keen eyes. Well. Maybe, I have dull ones. The plugin expects an array. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that your textboxArray elements are not jQuery object, try `$(textboxArray.get(0)).setCurrsorPosition(0);`

Comment: I think you have right direction. But textboxArray is jquery array in fact. Thing is the plugin expects array rather than element as this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: jQuery array doesn't mean all element in the array is a jQuery object. How did you create that array?

Comment: It's all jquery object because they are result from jquery selector. Anyway, I resolved the problem and happy again. Thanks for your answer.