# JQUERY Set Textarea Cursor to End of Text

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/adamadam123/gEEVM/4/

I'm building a chat system that allows users to add emoticons.

Just like in the jsfiddler example above I take the current text in the textarea, combine it with the chosen emoticon symbol and then add this text back into the textarea.

```
$(function() {
    var data = $('textarea').val();
    var emoticon = ':)';
    $('textarea').val(data + emoticon);
    $('textarea').focus();
});
```

The problem is when I set the focus back into the textarea the cursor is at the beginning of the text.

How can I set the cursor to the end of the text - to allow further typing?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Something simple you can do is reset the text area's value:

```
$(function() {
    var data = $('textarea').val();
    var emoticon = ':)';
    $('textarea').focus().val('').val(data + emoticon);
});
```

Comment: With this you stress the DOM when it happen frequently, you clear the textarea and then add a bunch of data AGAIN with some extra's. That's not an add,not a polite way to add data.

Answer (score 10):

First focus, then set value. Just like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gEEVM/5/)

```
$('textarea').focus();
$('textarea').val("New Text");
```

Another way is to add this after *.focus();*

```
$('textarea').val($('textarea').val() + ' ');
```

It adds a space to the end of the textarea thus focuses at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You should review this question:

[jQuery Set Cursor Position in Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area)

Most elegant JQuery solution from there:

```
$.fn.selectRange = function(start, end) {
    return this.each(function() {
        if (this.setSelectionRange) {
            this.focus();
            this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        } else if (this.createTextRange) {
            var range = this.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', end);
            range.moveStart('character', start);
            range.select();
        }
    });
};
```

> With this, you can do

```
$('#elem').selectRange(3,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

A **very** simple solution.

```
var emoticon = ':)';
var val = $('#textarea').val();
$('#textarea').select().val(val + emoticon);
```