# Set cursor to end of textarea- setSelectionRange() broken on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, textarea

My initial question is a direct dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003300/how-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-textarea-when-tabbed-into), trying to put the cursor at the end of a textarea.

```
one
two
three|<-- ideal position
```

It worked fine on all browsers except Firefox (I'm currently using version 18.0). Even the jsfiddle that Tim provided in the link above (for convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/DqtVK/40/) is not working.

It seems it's not highlighting or placing the cursor at all anymore.

I understand jquery is an alternative option (as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425363/jquery-set-textarea-cursor-to-end-of-text)) but did something happen on firefox's side that makes this method no longer reliable? Anyone have any insight? Is there a way to avoid the jquery route?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was an uncaught exception that was preventing my piece of code from finishing. It seems firefox really doesn't like focusing on a hidden piece of HTML. Lesson learned, make sure your target is visible!

Though why the jsfiddle is not working properly is still a mystery to me... 
but my base issue has been solved.

If anyone can explain the jsfiddle mystery, please keep respondin' I'll be on the lookout.