# How to use the focus in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a script where i can just click on a div and add information to a textarea. This is working, however the cursor is always at the start of the information that I inserted.

```
<div id="click">Click to insert</div>
<textarea id="info">I want to</textarea>
```

here is the jquery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#click').on('click',function(){
            var i=$('#info').val();
            var n="Insert this";//information to be inserted
            $('#info').val(i + n).focus();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now the entire thing should read **I want to insert this** followed by the cursor. Instead the cursor is in the middle like this **I want to [cursor] insert this**. Is there any way that I can have the cursor focus at the end of the contents in the fields?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609405/set-focus-after-last-character-in-text-box

Comment: Still not working. focus is still before the inserted text.

Comment: Did you try with the full SetCaretAtEnd function from the accepted answer? If so, you can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425363/jquery-set-textarea-cursor-to-end-of-text

Edit: If the element already has focus you may need to call `.blur()` beforehand.

Comment: You should probably start by replacing `$('click')` with `$('#click')` ! That's an error !!!!

Comment: See this post [jQuery Set Cursor Position in Text Area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out this one JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/2D9Td/ :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#click').on('click', function () {
        var i = $('#info').val();
        var n = "Insert this"; //information to be inserted
        $('#info').focus().val(i + n);
    });
});
```

Just changed the sequence of focus and val in last js call.

Comment: Remove the extra characters at the end of your link ):- so the link start working

Comment: Work perfectly. Thanks wiz kid.

Answer (score 0):

How about a jQuery plugin ?

```
$.fn.setCaretToEnd = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (this.setSelectionRange) {
            this.focus();
            this.setSelectionRange(this.value.length, this.value.length);
        } else if (this.createTextRange) {
            var range = this.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', this.value.length);
            range.moveStart('character', this.value.length);
            range.select();
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#click').on('click', function () {
        var i = $('#info').val();
        var n = "Insert this";

        $('#info').val(i + n).focus().setCaretToEnd();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vJWCz/1/)