# jQuery focus cursor after the value in firefox

Tags: jquery, html

I am doing a jQuery focus on a text field. In Chrome and IE the cursor starts after the value but in firefox it starts befoe the value.
How do I make it so it starts after the value in firefox?

Relevant code below:

```
$($.cookie("inputFocus")).focus()
```

Whole jQuery code below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#state").change(function () {
    this.form.submit();
})
var focus = $.cookie("inputFocus");
$(focus).focus();
$(focus)[0].setSelectionRange($(focus).val().length, $(focus).val().length);

$("#supplier_name").val($("#supplier_name").val());
$("#aircraft_type").val($("#aircraft_type").val());
var typingTimer;                
var doneTypingInterval = 600;  

$('#supplier_name').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('#supplier_name').val) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    }
    $.cookie("inputFocus", "#supplier_name"); 
});

$('#aircraft_type').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('#aircraft_type').val) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    }
    $.cookie("inputFocus", "#aircraft_type"); });
function GetQueryStringParams(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}

var state = GetQueryStringParams('state');
var supplier_name = GetQueryStringParams('supplier_name');
var aircraft_type = GetQueryStringParams('aircraft_type');

    if(supplier_name === "" && state === "any" && aircraft_type === "") {
            $('#clear').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    $("#clear").click(function() {
    if(state === "any") {
        $("#aircraft_type").val("");
        $("#supplier_name").val("");
    } else {
        $('#state option:selected').remove();
        $("#aircraft_type").val("");
        $("#supplier_name").val("");    
    }
    });

function doneTyping () {
    $("form").submit();
}

});
</script>
```

Comment: There is no jQuery solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area take a look at Marks solution

Comment: Maybe you missing ';' in somewhere (ex: line 4), so ff cannot understand your code. Correct all mistake and try again ^.^

Comment: @Stiger: you can ignore ; in javascript

Answer (score 5):

You can use [setSelectionRange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Input.setSelectionRange) to set the caret position.

Try my demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NytVr/):

```
$('input').focus();
$('input')[0].setSelectionRange($('input').val().length, $('input').val().length);
```

Comment: This seems to work the best cross-browser.  Here's a slightly more reusable version of the same thing: http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisMBarr/Jc9N8/3/

Comment: I have inserted that. Now I get the following error:

TypeError: $(...)[0] is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

$(focus)[0].setSelectionRange($(focus).val().length, $(focus).val().length);