# set cursor between 2 letters in contenteditable

Tags: javascript

How do I set the cursor between the a and the b below?

```
<div contenteditable = true id = "test">
  abcdefg
</div>
```

I have tried to play with ranges, but nothing is working for me. The below code selects the entire text, and there is no cursor. (This code is for Chrome)

```
sel =  window.getSelection();
range =  document.createRange();
node = document.getElementById("test");
range.setStart(node, 0);
range.setEnd(node, 1);
sel.addRange(range);
```

Comment: check these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area

Comment: That works for a textarea, but not for contenteditable. I created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5a9uD/  (uncomment the js line for textarea to see it working there )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
function setSelectionRange(aNode, aOffset) {

    aNode.focus();

    var sel     = window.getSelection(),
        range   = sel.getRangeAt(0);

    range.collapse(true);
    range.setStart(aNode.childNodes[0], aOffset),

    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}

setSelectionRange(document.getElementById("test"), 1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5a9uD/1/

If you look to MDN documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range.setStart you will see that this interface use a node not an element.

Comment: Here is the answer for a slightly more advanced example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358651/javascript-contenteditable-set-cursor-at-character-offset