# javascript contenteditable: set cursor at character offset

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I need to set the cursor at a specific character offset. In the example below, I'd want to, for example, set it between the "a" and the "b".

```
<ul contenteditable = true >
    <li id = "test">abcdef</li>
</ul>
```

I asked before and got this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5a9uD/1/

That worked great for the given example and for what I needed it for then. But it does not work with this example: http://jsfiddle.net/mdwWN/   It gets an IndexSizeError at

```
range   = sel.getRangeAt(0);
```

Comment: For a more general solution that works with nested HTML elements, you could try something like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16100733/96100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to pass **text container's** `childNodes[0]` to `range.setStart` function.
Check this out.

```
function setSelectionRange(aNode, childElem, aOffset) {

  aNode.focus();

  var sel = window.getSelection(),
  range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

  range.collapse(true);

  range.setStart(childElem.childNodes[0], aOffset),

  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}

var container = document.getElementById("test");
var childElement = document.getElementById('item1');
setSelectionRange(container, childElement, 1);
```

Here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdwWN/1/).