# How to move cursor to foundation reveal modal

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm using foundation reveal function.
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html

And the modal have text input area.

I want to set a cursor to input area when the modal is opened.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into this:
[jQuery Set Cursor Position in Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area)

The first answer there answers your question. The only difference is that you want the function to be fired when the modal is getting fired.