# tinymce 4 how to put cursor to end of the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, text-editor

For some reason, I need to execute :

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(text, {format : 'html'});
```

After that, how to put the cursor to the end of the text ?

Comment: Can you confirm that setting the content of the WHOLE editor is what you intended? (you are targeting activeEditor instead of "selection" ) and that works ONLY while the editor is empty, but when dealing with existing content your inserted text would replace the entire content (for which it doesn't make much sense you to want to place the cursor/caret at the end of the placed text, since it's easy to find the end)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
ed.selection.select(ed.getBody(), true); // ed is the editor instance
ed.selection.collapse(false);
```

This seems to be answered by Peter Wooster in thread [jQuery Set Cursor Position in Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area?rq=1)

EDIT For TINYMCE use:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.select(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody(), true);
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.collapse(false);
```

Comment: FYI.  If you are limiting character input and using this to continually set position at the end it will break in Chrome v40.  If it is called enough times the browser just freezes up.  Tested with a clean install of Chrome v40 on Windows 7 and 8.

Have not found a solution to this yet.

Comment: Second code part worked for me in Chrome and FF only on previously calling this command: tinymce.execCommand('mceFocus',false,'<editor_id>');

Comment: I am using tinyMCE with angular, when I attempted using this code to set the cursor it didn't appear to work. Possibly it was related to my specific environment, but I was able to get it to work by first setting the focus to the, then changing the cursor position by selecting and collapsing the selection (as described here). So it looked something like this:

tinyMCE.activeEditor.focus();
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.select(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody(), true);
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.collapse(false);