# Set cursor position in textbox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I want to set the cursor position to last character in textbox.

I'm using this code.

```
$("#txt_search").focus();
```

In **chrome** it is set cursor to last but in **mozilla** it is in first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use it like this:

```
var data = $('#txt_search').val();
$('#txt_search').focus().val('').val(data);
```

**[See this for javascript solution by CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/499158/1719752)**

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but it not working.I'll check your link may be it will help me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it.Using the [Jquery Caret](https://gist.github.com/DrPheltRight/1007907) script.
It is working in both **chrome** and **mozilla**.

Add jquery caret script in my file and used the following code.

```
var $inputExample = $('#txt_search');
$inputExample.caretToEnd();
```