# scrollTop() when toggle back to original state

Tags: jquery, html, web

So for one of my buttons, I made it so that when clicked, a div(#drowpdown) would drop down near the footer of the webpage and would scroll down as well where the anchor point is located.

Is there a way to scroll back up to the top of the website as the #dropdown is toggled to its original position ?

heres my html

```
        <div id = "button_hold">
            <a href = "#dropdown"><img id = "drop_button" src = "images/drop_button.png"/></a>
        </div>
        <div id = "dropdown">
            <p>here are some stuff</p>
        </div>
```

and the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#drop_button").click(function () {
      $("#dropdown").toggle('slide', {
         duration: 1000,
         easing: 'easeOutExpo',
         direction: 'up'
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Set Cursor Position in Text Area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#drop_button").click(function () {
       if ($("#dropdown").hasClass('slide')) {

           $("#dropdown").slideUp(300, function() {
               $("#dropdown").removeClass('slide');
               $('html, body').animate({
                   scrollTop: 0
               }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');
           });

       } else {

           $("#dropdown").slideDown(300, function(){
               $("#dropdown").addClass('slide');
               $('html, body').animate({
                   scrollTop: $('#dropdown').offset().top
               }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');
           });

       }
   });
});
```

Comment: I really like what you did ! But it seems to mess up my other jquery code

Comment: What does the '$("#dropdown").toggle('slide', {' do? Does it show/hide the element. If so I have updated my code above.

Comment: yeah, it shows/hides the element, when clicked a div slides down, and when clicked again, the div slides up.

Comment: seems to be having the same problem as earlier, it stops all the other jquery code I have in

Comment: Looks like there was a JS syntax issue before.

Comment: YES ! the code you just updated works like a charm ! Thank you so much ! I'm pretty new to if statements on jquery so this is pretty good study ! Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

To set a scroll position of an element, you can use the below:

```
$('#dropdown').scrollTop(0);
```