# Set cursor within text of input using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input-field

Using this topic:
[jQuery Set Cursor Position in Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area)

I write this code but it does not works:

```
<input id="myTextInput" type="text" value="some text2">
<input type="button" value="set mouse" id="btn" />
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn').on('click', function () {
        var inp = $('#myTextInput');        
        var pos = 3;
        inp.focus();
        if (inp.setSelectionRange) {
            inp.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
        } else if (inp.createTextRange) {
            var range = inp.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            if (pos < 0) {
                pos = $(this).val().length + pos;
            }
            range.moveEnd('character', pos);
            range.moveStart('character', pos);
            range.select();
        }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qeanb8gk/)

Where is my mistake?
Thanks

Comment: the correct search term is `caret`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that you select the jQuery object instead of DOM element: replace `var inp = $('#myTextInput');` with `var inp = $('#myTextInput')[0];`.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qeanb8gk/2/)

---

However, I'd recommend using the plugin from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/841121/1420197), since the code will look cleaner:

```js
$.fn.selectRange = function(start, end) {
  return this.each(function() {
    if (this.setSelectionRange) {
      this.focus();
      this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    } else if (this.createTextRange) {
      var range = this.createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      range.moveEnd('character', end);
      range.moveStart('character', start);
      range.select();
    }
  });
};


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    var pos = 7;
    $('#myTextInput').focus().selectRange(pos, pos);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myTextInput" type="text" value="some text2">
<input type="button" value="set mouse" id="btn" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need DOM element rather than JQuery object to use `setSelectionRange` or `createTextRange`.
Use `.get(0)` to retreive it.

```
var inp = $('#myTextInput');
inp.focus();
inp = inp.get(0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qeanb8gk/1/