# how to prevent unclearing a textbox when selection is made?

Tags: javascript, onclick, textarea, selection

I'm trying to build a texteditor and for that I'm using a textarea to fill in my text

My problem is when I click a button the textarea selection is gone.

Here is some code to show the problem:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    Address:<br>
    <textarea id="myTextarea">
    California Road
    </textarea>
    
    <p>Click the button to select the contents of the text area.</p>
    
    <button type="button">Try it</button>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @mplungjan — What benefit would it bring?

Comment: Because it's in a form and should not be empty

Comment: When I know the selected text I could add some tags @Quentin

Comment: I also tried input type = button @mplungjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selection is not lost, but just not shown when textarea is not focused.
Try this code on Firefox, Chrome or IE10:
http://jsfiddle.net/swwqd700/

HTML part:

```
Address:<br>
<textarea id="myTextarea">
California Road
</textarea>    
<p>Click the button to select the contents of the text area.</p>
<button id="button">Try it</button>
```

Javascript part:

```
function go() {
    var e = document.getElementById("myTextarea");
    var startPos = e.selectionStart;
    var endPos = e.selectionEnd;
    var selection = e.value.substring(startPos, endPos)    ;
    alert("It seems to have disappeared, but...\n\"" + selection + "\"");
    e.focus();
}
var btn = document.getElementById("button");
btn.addEventListener(
    "click",
    go,
    false
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add bbcode functionality you might want to have a look into this thread:

[jQuery Set Cursor Position in Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area)

Also this code (taken from Tim Down in this thread [Get the Highlighted/Selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text)) might help:

```
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}
```