# How to place cursor at the beginning of input box using with jquery inputmask?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input that I used with jquery inputmask. It works well, but what I want to do is to place the cursor to the beginning of the input box as the user click on the input box.

**Here is my input tag:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" data-mask="999999999?9" />
```

Please help me out from this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area

Comment: Please see my question, the one you mentioned is not using with jquery input mask.

Comment: I read the questions - as far as I can tell the top answer should work for you - does it not?

Comment: I'm so sorry, thank you for your help.
I can solve it now.