# javascript - Convert letter character from keyboard event to another character and insert that new character into input field (online keyboard layout)

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, converters

I am trying to make a function that will take a character, which is the value of the key pressed on the keyboard, convert it to another special character, and insert it into a particular input field (something like simulating another keyboard layout).

**Example**:

1. User type ***x*** on keyboard
2. The function takes this character and converts it into ***ḫ***
3. Than function insert this character into a particular input field

I made a function which converts those special characters:

```
$("input").keydown(function(e){
    var keyCharacter = e.key;
});

var replaceFrom = [/A/, /i/, /a/, /s/, /z/, /S/, /q/, /H/, /x/, /X/, /T/, /D/];
var replaceTo = ["ꜣ", "j", "ꜥ", "s", "z", "š", "q", "ḥ", "ḫ", "ẖ", "ṯ", "ḏ"];

function transliterationConverter(user_input, transliteration_schema_to_replace, transliteration_schema_for_replace) {
    for (i = 0; i < transliteration_schema_to_replace.length; i++) {
        user_input = user_input.replace(new RegExp(transliteration_schema_to_replace[i], "g"), transliteration_schema_for_replace[i]);
    }
    return user_input;
}

var convertedKeyCharacter = transliterationConverter(keyCharacter, replaceFrom, replaceTo);

// Character typed by user: x
// Desired result in input field: ḫ
```

P.S. I am not happy with a solution that includes taking value from the input field and then converts its characters to other ones, because if that happening, the user can see the "conversion process" that is happening in half of a second.

Comment: I need that function for converting user input into special transliteration letters used by Egyptologists for representing hieroglyphs as letters.

Comment: I don't need a translation in another field. I need that everything is happening in the same field because the user should enter those special characters in one field and submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of hiding not converted value from user, you gotta use event `keypress`,prevent default action and change each character manually, then append it to input value

UPDATED CHECK MY SOLUTION!!!

example:

```js
let element = document.querySelector('#something');
const replaceFrom = {'A': 'ꜣ', 'i': 'j', 'a':'ꜥ' , 's': 's', 'z':'z', 'S': "š", 'q': "q", 'H': "ḥ"}



element.addEventListener('keypress',function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let location  = this.selectionStart,
      result = '',newArr = [];
  let arr =  this.value.split('');
  let char = (typeof replaceFrom[event.key] == "undefined")?event.key:replaceFrom[event.key];
  arr.forEach((elem,index)=>{
    if(index == location ){
      newArr[index] = char;
      newArr[index+1] = elem;
    }
    else if(index>location)
      newArr[index+1] = elem;
    else
      newArr[index] = elem;
  })
  if(arr.length == 0)
    newArr[0] = char;
  else if(location == arr.length){
      newArr[location] = char;  
  }

  newArr.forEach(ch=>{
    result += ch;
  })
  this.value = result;
  this.selectionStart = location+1;
  this.selectionEnd = location+1;
})
```

```html
<input id="something">
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer.

Comment: @user3120612 check my answer  again

Comment: It works great with character conversion, but it does not work when I want to insert new character between existing ones, or if I select the part of the string and try to replace it with another character. Also, it put cursor always at the end, as letter typed.

Comment: To specify or get position of selected text inside input or text area use properties                  selectionStart and selectionEnd

Comment: i fixed first issue and guess you can handle next problem by yourself=)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need jQuery, in my example I use `window.onload` to attach a function to be run after the page load.

On page load, it will call `bindEvents`, this function is in charge of binding events on element within the `DOM` (which is now loaded).

Then if you only need to translate, you can make the translation `readonly`, and you can convert all the values at once.

I have replaced your two `arrays` with an object behaving like a `Map`, because it is a 1 to 1 relationship and it is easier to maintain and to read.

```js
window.onload = function init() {
  bindEvents();
}

function bindEvents() {
  document.querySelector('textarea[name="original"]').addEventListener('keyup', updateTranslation, true);
}


const translationMap = {
  A: 'ꜣ',
  i: 'j',
  a: 'ꜥ',
  s: 's',
  z: 'z',
  S: 'š',
  q: 'q',
  H: 'ḥ',
  x: 'ḫ',
  X: 'ẖ',
  T: 'ṯ',
  D: 'ḏ'
}

function updateTranslation(e) {
  const txtArea = document.querySelector('textarea[name="original"]');
  let txt = txtArea.value;
  let newTxt = '';
  
  for(let i = 0; i < txt.length; i += 1) {
    newTxt += translationMap[txt[i]] ? translationMap[txt[i]] : txt[i];
  }
  
  txtArea.value = newTxt;
}
```

```css
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-width">
  <h3>Input into special transliteration letters used by Egyptologists for representing hieroglyphs as letters</h3>
  <textarea name="original" placeholder="type here"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: It should allow the user to correct his input. It should behave like a regular field, but with character conversion.

Comment: @BorisJ. I have made the whole in the textarea for the translation, now you will need to add some tuning, for selecting and not losing the cursor position, for navigating with the keys, etc. This is due because you are rerendering the textarea while you are typing, forcing the cursor position to be set after the text upon replace.

Comment: It is a good solution. The only thing I don't like is that you can see the translation process. First, the character you typed appears, and then it is switched with another one. If only we could skip that step - that translation happens before character appears in the field - if it is possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-the-caret-column-not-pixels-position-in-a-textarea-in-characters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968174/set-text-cursor-position-in-a-textarea

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try to improve your function to include those cursor positions.

Comment: Sorry, I am out of time, I think in your case it would be more adapted to use a custom component rather than a textarea, you need to reprogram a textarea with a different behavor.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to prevent the text from being displayed in a textarea, maybe you should wait for some other people feedback. Generally I try to avoid reflowing a component that I am currently editing.

Comment: No problem, you did quite a lot to help me.

Comment: Maybe put an invisible textarea directly on top of the translated textarea. Of course, you'd probably have to use a fixed-width font for this to be effective.... and then there's scrolling to deal with. But just throwing out ideas.