# Caret Position after appending to input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append various things to an input with buttons.

button#addNumber -> appends `245`

button#addOperation -> appends `+`

A problem arises with button#radicSign.

I want to add the template for a square root `sqrt()` and place the caret inside the parentheses afterwards for the user to type in the number.

Is this possible?`
If yes, is it worth the effort? Or should I open a dialog box and insert it then?

```
$('button#radicSign').on('click', function add2digit() {
    addOperation('sqrt');
  });

function addOperation(op) {
    var problemInput = $('input#testProblem');
    problemInput.val(problemInput.val() + op);
}
```

Comment: Add the code snippet please, here or on https://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: there is no code snippet. everything is really basic. i just want to know how i can place the caret between the parentheses after i have appended `sqrt()`
but there you go, i added the code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area

Comment: @user1702401 that's not it. i don't want a fixed offset, but the position RIGHT between the parentheses, wherever they are inserted (could be first thing in the string, could be 30 chars in)

Comment: @user1702401, while very useful, doesn't fully answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this to achieve what you want:

```
$('#sqrt').click(function() {
  var length = $('#a').val().length;
  $('#a').val($('#a').val()+'sqrt()');
  $('#a').focus()[0].setSelectionRange(length+5, length+5);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4bb18opy/)

Comment: mhhhhh.. the idea looks right... but i think that's also not quite the solution. you have to know: there can (and probably will) be other stuff before the sqrt() in the string. so assume the string is `2453 + 423 - 244 +`, now i want to append a `sqrt(144)`. an empty `sqrt()` has to be appended to the string with the caret placed between the `()`. all is happening in the same input field

Comment: oh wow really didn't see the fiddle. that's exactly what i wanted, thanks :)

Comment: No worries, haha, I was really confused for a moment.

Comment: oh well now i have yet another problem...
your solution works fine. but now i want to be able to insert a number per button click between the parentheses (click sqrt, then click 3-digit number -> 3-digit number between the parentheses)
but i have set it to `append()`. how can i write directly to the caret position? :)

Comment: You'll have to pull the current value, add in the number in the string where you want it using something like `.slice()`, then update the value of the text input.  You could also convert the string to an array, and use `.splice()` to add in the number at the specified index.