# Have user selection a certain point of text input with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text input.

```
<input type="text" id="foo" name="bar" value="11 Minutes"/>
```

[image: 11 Minutes]

I want it so when the user clicks on the input, that the user's "Cursor" or "Selector" is after the 11, not after the Minutes.

I do not know where to begin, if this is possible across browsers, and have been unable to find information on this.

Decent browser support should be considered as well.

Comment: check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0g7x9v5c/)

Comment: @guradio That is just removing the ` Minutes` part. I need to keep it, but place the selector between it and the number.

Comment: I think you have to set the focus youself at str.len - 7 (Minutes str len)

Comment: @AlonEitan that may be useful, but this question is not about selecting text, but having the selector be in a different location than the end.

Comment: @MadeInDreams I understand the str len but not how I can use it to move the focus.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area Look at the accepted answer. In your case start and end should be the same I guess

Comment: @MadeInDreams that one is much closer to my question. Thank you. This was difficult to search for because of the lack of language around the pipe selector character while typing input. Cursor isn't accurate language for it. You can close this or answer the question if you please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I don't know if this will work for you . but basically I'm setting the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` on where do you want the cursor to be placed.

You can also play with the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`. adding range between those two would result too highlighted selections.
Just make it sure that start < end and you're good.

```js
$(document).on("click", function(e){
  if (e.target && e.target.id == "foo") {
    if ($(e.target).is(":focus")) {
      e.target.selectionStart = 2;
      e.target.selectionEnd = 2;
    }
  }
  
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="foo" name="bar" value="11 Minutes"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```