# Restrict HTML input to fixed length digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am designing an HTML input to accept phone numbers (10 digits). I want the input form to be pre-filled with '-'s. When users input numbers, the '-'s should be replaced by the actual numbers. Similarly, when users delete numbers, they should be replaced by '-'s.

Here is what I achieved: https://jsfiddle.net/f99obu18/2/.

Javascript code (with jQuery):

```
$("form input").val("-".repeat(10));
$("form").on('keypress keydown', 'input', function(event) {
    // Replaces the "-" while user input.
    var index = this.selectionStart;
    if (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) {
      $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, index) + 
                  $(this).val().substring(index + 1, $(this).val().length));
      setCaretToPos(this, index);
    } 
    // Adds "-" at the current position for "Backspace."
    if (event.keyCode == 8 && index > 0) {
      $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, index) + '-' +
                  $(this).val().substring(index, $(this).val().length));
      setCaretToPos(this, index);
    } 
    // Adds "-" at the current position for "Delete."
    if (event.keyCode == 46) {
      $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, index) + '-' +
                  $(this).val().substring(index + 1, $(this).val().length));
      setCaretToPos(this, index);
      return false;
    }
});
```

(The setCaretToPos method is taken from [jQuery Set Cursor Position in Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area/499158#499158).)

**Question:** The solution looks good on my computer, but doesn't work on my phone. Is there standard, re-usable code (e.g., jQuery plugins) for this input validation?

Comment: Mobile browsers usually do not register `keypress` event. `keydown` or `keyup` however should work but you only need to separate different events in first argument of `$.on()` with a space. There is no need for a comma.

Comment: You also need to check this, when i go to the end(caret at the end) and press `del` key, it keeps adding hyphens.

Comment: @josephting Thank you for the reply. It works on my phone, but not pad. Do you know why?

Comment: @JonesVinothJoseph Thank you, I have fixed it.

Comment: @josephting The new URL is https://jsfiddle.net/f99obu18/4/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery plugin [masked-input-plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) may help.

With the plugin, change your code to:

```
$("form input").mask("9999999999",{placeholder:"-"});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for.