# Position of Cursor in <textarea>

Tags: html

I have code like this...

```html
<textarea name="message" id="body" rows="15" cols="45">

In reply to:
Hi there.  Did you get my message?
</textarea>
```

I'd like the cursor to be automatically positioned in the upper left corner, but because of the space/text between the `<textarea>` tags, it gets positioned in the bottom-ish right.

Is there some javascript or something that can force the cursor to be where I want it?

Comment: I think I've solved this, take a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var txtarea = document.getElementById("body");
    txtarea.selectionEnd = 0;
</script>
```

Edited:
Try this:

```
$("#body").focus(function() {
    $(this).prop("selectionEnd", 0);
});
```

Comment: This didn't work.  The original question has been revised to be able to run the code snippet.  If you "tab" to get into the text area, you'll notice that the cursor is positioned at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited the whole answer. I think I understand your question correctly now and I have found a solution.

The code works for me as is in Chrome and Opera, but not in Firefox, IE and Edge.
I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area) on how to place the caret in any position in a textarea and now it works with your example in the browsers mentioned above (haven't tested IE below 11).

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bume1up1/2/

The javascript I copied from the SO link above:

```
function setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
  if (input.setSelectionRange) {
    input.focus();
    input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
  }
  else if (input.createTextRange) {
    var range = input.createTextRange();
    range.collapse(true);
    range.moveEnd('character', selectionEnd);
    range.moveStart('character', selectionStart);
    range.select();
  }
}

function setCaretToPos (input, pos) {
  setSelectionRange(input, pos, pos);
}

setCaretToPos(document.getElementById("body"), 0);
```

In some browsers the textarea will be in focus by default, in Firefox you have to tab into the box, but the cursor position remains at the top.