# Cursor position in an editable div with a :before pseudo-element

Tags: html, css

I have an editable div with `:before` and `:after` css pseudo-elements.

The `:before` sets a prompt in the div
The `:after` acts like a placeholder

When the user clicks in an empty div, the cursor is placed before the "prompt" content.
Once the user starts typing the `:after` content disappears and the cursor is in the right spot.

Is there a way to have the cursor positioned after the content when an empty div is selected?
What is interesting is if there is any text in the div and you select the div the cursor goes to the end (as I want).

Any thoughts/help would be most appreciated.

```css
div[data-prompt][contenteditable=true]:before {
  content: attr(data-prompt);
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

div[data-placeholder]:empty:after {
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable='true' id="tbl01_r2c2" data-type="2" data-prompt="I will " data-placeholder="..."></div>
```

Cursor position when empty div is selected

[image]

Also note that the "prompt" will not always be the same length.

Comment: This question may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can consider text-indent and some translation to control the cursor position. Apply this only when the div is `:empty`

```css
div[data-prompt][contenteditable=true]:before {
  content: attr(data-prompt);
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

div[data-placeholder]:empty:after {
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  color: black;
  /* added */
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(-28px);
  text-indent: 0;
  /**/
}

/* added */
div[data-placeholder]:empty {
  text-indent: 38px;
}
div[data-prompt][contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(-37px);
  text-indent: 0;
}
/**/

div[data-prompt][contenteditable=true] {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable='true' id="tbl01_r2c2" data-type="2" data-prompt="I will " data-placeholder="..."></div>
```

For a more generic way you can rely on CSS variables:

```css
div[data-prompt][contenteditable=true]:before {
  content: attr(data-prompt);
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

div[data-placeholder]:empty:after {
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  color: black;
  /* added */
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(calc(10px - var(--d)));
  text-indent: 0;
  /**/
}

/* added */
div[data-placeholder]:empty {
  text-indent: var(--d);
}
div[data-prompt][contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(calc(1px - var(--d)));
  text-indent: 0;
}
/**/

div[data-prompt][contenteditable=true] {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div style="--d:37px;" contenteditable='true' id="tbl01_r2c2" data-type="2" data-prompt="I will " data-placeholder="..."></div>


<div style="--d:64px;" contenteditable='true' id="tbl01_r2c2" data-type="2" data-prompt="I will not " data-placeholder="..."></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  Can you think of a way to make it a bit more dynamic?  By that I mean to allow for different prompt lengths.